# Value of real type incorrectly compares

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, floating-point, numeric

I have field of `REAL` type in db. I use PostgreSQL. And the query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field = 0.15
```

does not return rows in which the value of `my_field` is `0.15`.

But for instance the query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field > 0.15
```

works properly.

How can I solve this problem and get the rows with `my_field = 0.15` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To *solve* your problem use the data type [**`numeric`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) instead, which is not a floating point type, but an arbitrary precision type.

If you enter the [numeric literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC) `0.15` into a `numeric` (same word, different meaning) column, the *exact* amount is stored - unlike with a `real` or `float8` column, where the value is coerced to next possible binary approximation. This may or may not be exact, depending on the number and implementation details. The decimal number 0.15 happens to fall between possible binary representations and is stored with a tiny error.

Note that the result of a calculation can be inexact itself, so be still wary of the `=` operator in such cases.

It also depends *how* you test. When comparing, Postgres coerces diverging numeric types to a type that can best hold the result.
Consider this **demo**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(num_r real, num_n numeric);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (0.15, 0.15);

SELECT num_r, num_n  
     , num_r = num_n       AS test1           --> FALSE
     , num_r = num_n::real AS test2           --> TRUE
     , num_r - num_n       AS result_nonzero  --> float8
     , num_r - num_n::real AS result_zero     --> real
FROM   t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bd3ea5149ff9b334bf6c19991af8cc85)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9a5b9c/1)</sub>

Therefore, if you have entered `0.15` as numeric literal into your column of data type `real`, you can find all such rows with:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field = real '0.15'
```

Use `numeric` columns if you need to store fractional digits exactly.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem originates from [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

`0.15` is not `0.15`, but `0.15000000596046448` (assuming double precision), as it can not be exactly represented as a binary floating point number.

([check this calculator](http://users.minet.uni-jena.de/~sack/SS04/download/IEEE-754.html))

Why is this a problem? In this case, most likely because the other side of the comparison uses the exact value 0.15 - through an exact representation, like a `numeric` type. (Cleared up on suggestion by **Eric**)

So there are two ways:

- use a format that actually stores the numbers in decimal format - as **Erwin** suggested

  - (or at least use the same type across the board)
- use rounding as **Jack** suggested - which has to be used carefully (by the way this uses a `numeric` type too, to exactly represent 0.15...)

**Recommended reading:**
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

<sub>(Sorry for the terse answer...)</sub>

Comment: This is not an accurate description of the problem. Given that `0.15` is some approximation (in IEEE 754 64-bit binary, it is exactly 0.1499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375), then it is always that approximation. Storing it, retrieving it, and comparing it for equality to `0.15` yields true. So the actual problem is that a different value was computed somewhere. This is not a floating-point problem; it happens with integers too. Producing the “same” mathematical result in different ways produces unequal numbers. For example, with integers, `100/3*3` does not equal `100*3/3`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right. But the most important thing here, which a lot of - even experienced - developers don't have in their minds is that "harmless" numbers are not always innocent. OP _expected_ 0.15 to be exactly 0.15 - as most likely he has an exact  datatype on the other side of the check. If people are aware of how floating point works, it is less likely to be a problem. Again: all your statements hold, but in my opinion, this piece of knowledge can not be repeated enough. I edited my answer to be more complete. (Your integer example is a different case, but good to keep in mind)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't see your data, but I'm guessing that `my_field` doesn't exactly equal 0.15. Try:

```
select * from my_table where round(my_field::numeric,2) = 0.15;
```

Comment: What is round()? Does PostgreSQL have this function?? I get `ERROR:  function round(real, integer) does not exist`

Comment: Oops, the first argument of [round()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-math.html) has to be numeric. Just cast appropriately (or, as Erwin points out in his answer, make `my_field` numeric in the first place). Lemme edit.

Comment: The fact that accuracy is important to me. So this function does not solve my problem.

Comment: @MikeBrown - Well, if accuracy is that important, then you already have your answer: none of the values of `my_field` equal 0.15. Other than using a `numeric` datatype for `my_field`, you can check to see if, eg, `abs(my_field - 0.15) < 0.0001` (or whatever tolerance you want).

Answer (score 1):

Considering both PPTerka's and Jack's answer.

```
Approximate numeric data types do not store the exact values specified for many numbers;
```

Look here for MS' decription of real values.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx