# Postgres real rounds to 4 decimal places

Tags: postgresql, types, precision

I have a column `latitude` of type `real` in my Postgres table.

Looking at it in Postico, it has the value of `57.70887`.
But selecting it from psql or via code, the value returned is rounded to 4 decimal places:

```
# SELECT latitude from categories where id = 4;

 latitude
----------
  57.7089
(1 row)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Postgres 9.6.

Comment: [extra_float_digits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, that is correct. `SET extra_float_digits = 3;` ➜ `select ..` ➜ `57.7088699`. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Znarkus just a off topic hint: if you're storing latitudes, I assume you're dealing with longitudes too ;-) so I would really recommend you to use the `postgis` extension for storing points. I might seem in the beginning a bit unnecessary, but when spatial queries are involved, it can absolutely save you a lot of trouble. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

The column should not be `real` if you care for precision. Floating point types only store approximate values. Use [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) instead  to preserve the value exactly as inserted.

Consider:

- [Value of real type incorrectly compares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236784/value-of-real-type-incorrectly-compares/18236909#18236909)
- [How to round REAL type to NUMERIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576685/how-to-round-real-type-to-numeric/21586899#21586899)
- [Can the Postgres data type NUMERIC store signed values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381974/can-the-postgres-data-type-numeric-store-signed-values/35375346#35375346)